# Analytic continuation of a series raised to a power raised to a power?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, proof-verification, dirichlet-series, analytic-continuation

### Background

I recently realized I could construct the below formula:

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1 }(1-x)(\sum_{r=1}^\infty b_r x^{r^\kappa} ) = (\sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty \frac{ b_\tilde r }{\tilde r  ^\kappa}) \frac{1}{\zeta(\kappa)} $$

Is it correct? I was wondering if it already existed in the literature? Is it possible to write the series $\sum_{r=1}^\infty b_r x^{r^\kappa}$ be expressed as a Laurent series? If so what is the next term?

### Proof

Consider the following expression:

$$ x^{s^\kappa} + x^{(2 s)^{\kappa}} + x^{(3s)^\kappa} + x^{(4s)^\kappa} + \dots = \frac{ x^{s^\kappa} }{1 - x^{s^\kappa}}$$

Let us write this in summation notation:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{(rs)^\kappa} = \frac{ x^{s^\kappa} }{1 - x^{s^\kappa}}$$

Let us multiply both sides with an arbitrary constant $a_\tilde r$:

$$ a_\tilde r \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{(rs)^\kappa} = a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{s^\kappa} }{1 - x^{s^\kappa}}$$

Let us take $s \to \tilde r s$:

$$ a_\tilde r \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{(r \tilde r)  s^\kappa} = a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa} }{1 - x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa}}$$

Let us sum of $\tilde r$ from $1$ to $\infty$:

$$ \sum_{\tilde r=1}^\infty  (a_\tilde r \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{(r \tilde r  s)^\kappa})= \sum_{\tilde r=1}^\infty  a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa} }{1 - x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa}}$$

Now let us write the L.H.S sum in it's full glory!
$$ \sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa} }{1 - x^{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa}} =$$
$$ a_1 (x^{s^\kappa} + x^{(2 s)^{\kappa}} + x^{(3s)^\kappa} + x^{(4s)^\kappa} + \dots) $$
$$ +$$
$$ a_2 (0 + x^{(2 s)^{\kappa}} + 0 + x^{(4s)^\kappa} + 0 + \dots)$$
$$ +$$
$$ a_2 (0 + x^{(2 s)^{\kappa}} + 0 + x^{(4s)^\kappa} + 0 + \dots)$$
$$ +$$
$$ a_3 (0 + 0 + x^{(3s)^\kappa} + 0 + 0 + \dots) $$
$$\vdots$$
Vertically summing the terms and defining the coefficients $b_r$:
$$ \underbrace{a_1}_{b_1} x^{s^\kappa} + \underbrace{(a_1 + a_2)}_{b_2} x^{(2s)^\kappa}  + \underbrace{(a_1+a_3)}_{b_3} x^{(3s)^\kappa}  + \dots = \sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{\tilde r  s^\kappa} }{1 - x^{\tilde r  s^\kappa}} $$
Hence, $b_r = \sum_{k} a_k$ where the permissible values of $k$ are the factors of $r$ . Now let us take this expression and multiply both sides with $(1-x)$

$$ (1-x)(b_1 x^{s^\kappa} + b_2 x^{(2s)^\kappa} + b_3 x^{(3s)^\kappa} + \dots) =  \sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty a_\tilde r \frac{ x^{\tilde r  s^\kappa} }{1 - x^{\tilde r  s^\kappa}} (1-x) $$

Taking limit both sides and using L' Hopital Rule for the R.H.S:

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1 }(1-x)(b_1 x^{s^\kappa} + b_2 x^{(2s)^\kappa} + b_3 x^{(3s)^\kappa} + \dots) = \lim_{ x \to 1 } \sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty \frac{ a_\tilde r }{(\tilde r  s)^\kappa}  $$

Let us now take $s \to 1$ both sides:

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1 }(1-x)(b_1 x + b_2 x^{(2)^\kappa} + b_3 x^{(3)^\kappa} + \dots) =  \sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty \frac{ a_\tilde r }{\tilde r  ^\kappa} $$

Now using the mobius inversion formula we have:

$$ \lim_{ x \to 1 }(1-x)(b_1 x + b_2 x^{(2)^\kappa} + b_3 x^{(3)^\kappa} + \dots) =  (\sum_{\tilde r = 1}^\infty \frac{ b_\tilde r }{\tilde r  ^\kappa}) \frac{1}{\zeta(\kappa)} $$

Comment: Is the first line of the proof correct?

Comment: The first line of the proof is incorrect for any $\kappa \ne 1$. for larger $\kappa$ this defines a "lacunary" series and no nice closed forms are available for such (A keyword for further search might be "transseries").

Answer (score 1):

You wrote
$\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{(rs)^k} 
= \frac{ x^{s^k} }{1 - x^{s^k}}
$.

But
$\frac{ x^{s^k} }{1 - x^{s^k}}
= \sum_{r=1}^\infty (x^{s^k})^r
= \sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{rs^k}
$
and
$rs^k
\ne (rs)^k
=r^ks^k
$
except for $k=1$.